# Running WSO2 Carbon as Web Application in Tomcat

Tags: tomcat, wso2

I'm trying to run WSO2 Carbon as a web application in Apache Tomcat. I've followed the procedure discussed at http://pradeepfernando.blogspot.com/2012/09/running-wso2-carbon-as-web-app-apache.html.

I've added the web application folders into Tomcat `webapps` folder, configured HTTPS listener of Tomcat. Server logs show that application is successfully deployed and OSGI console is started. When I try to connect to application from `https://localhost:8443/crbn/carbon`, I get a 404 error. There are no exceptions in server logs.

Tomcat error screen contains reference to `BridgeServlet: /crbn/carbon`, so I know that 
request is correctly forwarded to BridgeServlet. I guess BridgeServlet can not locate and run the application from OSGI bundles.  But I do not have any idea about why and how I can fix it.

How can I diagnose the problem, or is there any available source of information for the correct procedure?

Note: I'm using WSO2 Carbon 4.1.0, Apache Tomcat 7.0.40. I've tried Java versions 6 and 7.

Comment: I have added a JIRA improvement for WSO2 to re-support this deployment mode.  Please vote on the JIRA if this is something you would like to see: https://wso2.org/jira/browse/CARBON-14147

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We stopped supporting webapp deployment from carbon 4.X.X and later versions.