# limitations of running WSO2 Carbon 4.x and WSO2 Carbon based products in webapp mode?

Tags: wso2, wso2-data-services-server, wso2-identity-server, wso2-esb

WSO2 Carbon is not officially supported in webapp mode (see the selected answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16959326/can-wso2-carbon-4-1-run-as-a-web-app-war)).  However, I have no choice - If I want to run carbon, it must be run in webapp mode.

There are some detailed instructions [here](http://pradeepfernando.blogspot.co.uk/2012/09/running-wso2-carbon-as-web-app-apache.html) for setting up carbon 4.x in webapp mode.

I am concerned is that standalone mode is strongly recommended by WSO2.

**My Questions are:**  What are the limitations:

1. when running Carbon 4.x in webapp mode?
2. when running other Carbon based products (e.g. ESB, AS, etc) in webapp mode?

If possible, please provide a detailed list of the limitations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Limitations:

1. When you take the ESB, as you might have seen it exposes ports 8280/8243 (HTTP/HTTPS) in addition to 9763/9443 which is exposed through the servlet transport. In the case of ESB you need (and want) to use port 8280/8243 when you're interacting with the ESB because those are the two non-blocking high performant transports. When you deploy ESB on top of another web container, you're limited by the servlet transports provided by the container. So we can't get the desired performance out of the ESB for proxying and other scenarios.
2. Complexities involving using web container functionalities. Carbon has its own clustering/caching/security etc... infrastructure. When you deploy Carbon as a webapp then we should look at supporting all those functions provided by the container for different containers. Which is complex, not consistent and in some cases sub-optimal

IMHO those were the two most important factors why it's discouraged to deploy Carbon on top of other containers. Going with a standalone deployment approach it has contributed immensely to not include web container specific "hacks" into the platform to get things done and have a much cleaner consistent platform.

Comment: The above limitations may mean that webapp deployment is still suitable for smaller, low volume deployments, and may still be suitable for me in certain cases.  However, I would need to know ALL of the concerns that need to be handled by "me" when using the webapp deployment method.  Would you be able to list the extra concerns where you have put "etc..." in your answer?

Comment: I don't know Chris. Personally I haven't, I'm not sure if anyone has, explored and jotted down every nook and corner of what will go wrong (or the list of things you should be aware of) when you do this. If you go down this path you're pretty much on your own and have to tackle problems as and when they arrive because even if you take 2 versions of say for example, WebLogic, might yield different errors.

Comment: Many thanks for the response.  I guess I will start with the approach of trying a tiny bit of WSO2 functionality and a simple use case that is easy to test.

Answer (score 0):

One issues with deploying Carbon in web-app mode is that this deployment model is not supported by WSO2.  I will add more issues to this answer as I encounter them...

Comment: Standalone mode is strongly recommended, but web-app mode is still supported in carbon 4.0. Have a look at: http://pradeepfernando.blogspot.com/2012/09/running-wso2-carbon-as-web-app-apache.html

Comment: @RajeevSampath - do you mean webapp mode is still supported by WSO2? or, do you mean webapp will work, but is unsupported by WSO2?

Comment: I tried with the steps above but no success with carbon version 4.7.0

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, webapp is not supported... Please refer this thread :[Running WSO2 Carbon as Web Application in Tomcat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16588575/running-wso2-carbon-as-web-application-in-tomcat)

Regards,

Mohan