# WSO2 Governance Registry 4.6 and Single Sign On Without Identity Server

Tags: tomcat, wso2

I am exploring the latest G-Reg and wanted to implement SSO (so that users will NOT see the log in screen). However, all documented solutions involve Identity Server, which we wanted to avoid (an additional product to maintain). The firm already has a standard way of deployment a web app into Tomcat environment and leverage Jcifs (Active Direcory and NTLM) for all SSO needs. Knowing that WSO2 products run on Carbon (OSGi model), So I want to approach the SSO solution from two angles:

1. to run G-Reg as a stand-alone app (as is) how can I implement SSO with LDAP/Active Directory without involving Identity Server?
2. tried to make the G-Reg as a web app based on http://pradeepfernando.blogspot.com/2012/09/running-wso2-carbon-as-web-app-apache.html. However, I got "BridgeServlet error" (per [Running WSO2 Carbon as Web Application in Tomcat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16588575/running-wso2-carbon-as-web-application-in-tomcat) ). so I am wondering if this approach is still valid.

Please advise and I appreciate your help.

Thank you

Yang

Comment: AFAIK since carbon relies on p2, you can configure all from scratch to run as you want.